# Regex for matching substring, but not containing word (word boundary issue)

Tags: regex

I have 100,000 files (mostly office-type files).  I'm using Excel VBA to check all the filenames that contain the word "list", but trying to avoid false positives (such as "specialist").

The answer provided for "Regex for matching substring, but not containing word" is very nearly what's required ( `\b(?!String)\w*ring\w*\b` ) except that my filenames do not have neat word boundaries.

The current pattern `\b(?!specialist)\w*list\w*\b` correctly ignores some variants (`3 Specialist`, `6-specialist`, `Specialists` etc).  Is it possible to modify the pattern so that it correctly weeds out the following variants as well: `1Specialist`, `2_specialist` and `Xspecialists?`  If so, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks for any assistance/advice,
M

Here's the recursive subroutine that I've been using (apologies for poor formatting):

```
Sub RecursiveFolderPATTERN(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, _IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

'Declare the variables
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim NextRow As Long

Dim objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = "([^A-Za-z]|^)(address|info|data)?lists?([^A-Za-z]|$)"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

'Find the next available row
NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Loop through each file in the folder
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If objRegExp.test(objFile) Then
Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = objFile.Name
Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = objFile.Size
Cells(NextRow, "F").Value = objFile.Type
Cells(NextRow, "G").Value = objFile.DateCreated
Cells(NextRow, "H").Value = objFile.DateLastAccessed
Cells(NextRow, "I").Value = objFile.DateLastModified
Cells(NextRow, "J").Value = objFile.Path
NextRow = NextRow + 1
End If
Next objFile

'Loop through files in the subfolders
If IncludeSubfolders Then
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.Subfolders
    Call RecursiveFolderPATTERN(objSubFolder, True)
Next objSubFolder
End If

End Sub
```

Answer edit: Changing the line `If objRegExp.test(objFile) Then` into `If objRegExp.test(objFile.Name) Then` fixed the issue.

Alternative answer edit: Changing the pattern from `"([^A-Za-z]|^)(address|info|data)?lists?([^A-Za-z]|$)"` to `"(^(?!.*specialist).*list.*$)"` also works well. Both approaches have their advantages, so I intend to use both of them.

Comment: So you want to match `list` except when preceded by `special`? i.e. match `survivalist` but don't match `specialist`?

Comment: Hi Sergio, In essence, yes.  I'm looking to identify any old files that might contain PII (personally identifiable information), with a view to permanently deleting them. One identifier is that the filename contains the string "list" - but we have a lot of files that contain the string "specialist".  Unfortunately the naming systems are inconsistent (some filenames have spaces, others use underscores etc), hence the word boundary issue.

Comment: What about the words "globalistics" or "fatalistic"?

Comment: Hi Andrei, I'm only really concerned with "specialist" - and the other answer thread is getting pretty close to achieving what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to find filenames that match to "list" but don't match "specialist", try [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/uFol7S/5):

```
(?i)^(?!.*specialist).*list.*$
```

**EDIT**

Delete the `(?i)` from the pattern and test it with the following snippet:

```
Sub RecursiveFolderPATTERN()
  Dim objRegExp As Object, arrStrings() As String, _
      i As Long, objMatch As Object
  Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  With objRegExp
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = "^(?!.*specialist).*list.*$"
  End With
  Dim TestString As String
  TestString = "3 Specialist" & vbNewLine & _
               "6-specialist" & vbNewLine & _
               "Specialists" & vbNewLine & _
               "true SpeciaList" & vbNewLine & _
               "1 Specialist" & vbNewLine & _
               "2_specialist" & vbNewLine & _
               "Xspecialists" & vbNewLine & _
               "TheListOfSpecialists.xlsx" & vbNewLine & _
               "List" & vbNewLine & _
               "lISTs" & vbNewLine & _
               "Globalistics" & vbNewLine & _
               "GlobalList.doc" & vbNewLine & _
               "fatalistic" & vbNewLine & _
               "The big list of PII.csv" & vbNewLine & _
               "A few lISTs with something.xls"
  arrStrings = Split(TestString, vbNewLine)
  For i = LBound(arrStrings) To UBound(arrStrings)
    If objRegExp.Test(arrStrings(i)) Then
      Debug.Print arrStrings(i)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: By the way this doesn't match "specialist list", not sure if it's a problem.

Comment: It is necessary to know that the "specialist" or the "list" is more important.

Comment: @CallumWatkins, if the "list" is more important, then it is possible to try `(?i)^.*(?<!specia)list.*$`.

Comment: Hi Andrei, many thanks for the suggestions.  I must be doing something wrong because I get run-time error 5017 when I use either of these patterns in the Excel macro, whereas Callum's patterns run fine. Obviously this is a shame, because it looks extremely useful.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for posting this - it looks really interesting. Unfortunately I won’t be able to try this until Wednesday - but will let you know how I get on. All the best, Martin.

Comment: And that pattern works just fine in my macro - great stuff! Many thanks, Martin

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
([^A-Za-z]|^)list([^A-Za-z]|$)
```

It would match the word "list" that is not surrounded by other letters.

Or should some words containing "list" be acceptable?

[Try it out](https://regex101.com/r/d493rS/1)

EDIT: To allow matching the word "lists" it can be changed to this:

```
([^A-Za-z]|^)lists?([^A-Za-z]|$)
```

EDIT 2: To whitelist some prefixes, you can change it to this (whitelists "address", "info" and "data" as prefixes for example purposes):

```
([^A-Za-z]|^)(address|info|data)?lists?([^A-Za-z]|$)
```

Comment: Thanks Callum.  This nearly, nearly, nearly works with my simple test folder (containing filenames with different variants of "specialist" and "list".  It correctly skips all the "specialist" variants, and reports 7 out of 9 "list" variants.  The 2 it misses are "Addresslist" and "Lists" - where "list" is adjacent to a letter.  Even so, this is a big step forward!

Comment: @user8751653 The problem that I can see is that your requirements are not very well defined. It would be hard to detect something like addresslist unless you specifically whitelist it in the regex.

Comment: Thanks again, Callum - I'll take a good look (but it probably won't be until Monday).  Have a good weekend!

Comment: Hi Callum, this is indeed a further improvement and probably one that I can now develop further (thank you).  One interesting point to note is that the macro containing this regex is now generating false positives, if the folder containing the file has "list" in its name (even if it's not actual in the filename).  The regex approach is proving to be harder than I imagined!

Comment: @user8751653 I’m not sure how you are using the regular expression on your end, but you shouldn’t be getting false positives. Are you running it against the full path to the file?

Comment: It's almost certainly user error (given that I'm not very experienced at this).  I'm using a recursive subroutine that crawls through all the subfolders within a specified folder/directory.  This seems to work fine when I'm looking for a specific substring in the filename of any of the files contained within that directory - and I can get it to report various details (such as path name etc).  Trying to modify the existing routine to fold in the regex is probably where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @user8751653 my only guess is that you need to run the regex against the file name instead of the full path. If you still need more help on this you can post your current code in your question as an edit and I or someone else can take a look for you.

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated.  I'll need to master how to post code correctly first!

Comment: @user8751653 There's a guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) that tells you how to add code formatted nicely.

Comment: The guide's useful (thank you) - but my subroutine is too long to post as a comment, so I guess it's alright to post it as an answer to my own question?

Comment: @user8751653 no, post it as an edit to your question, in a similar way to how I edited my answer.

Comment: @user8751653 So I'm not a VBA expert, but it looks like you are implicitly casting each `objFile` to a string and running the regex against that. This could mean that changing the line `If objRegExp.test(objFile) Then` into `If objRegExp.test(objFile.Name) Then` could work.